# В массив поступают не все элементы

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть такой код:

```
void TrafficLight::setTimeLights (int seconds[], int sizeSeconds) {

    // Doubling seconds per traffic light (greenyellow + red)
    int greens[sizeSeconds];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeSeconds; i++) {

        seconds[i] *= 2;
        greens[i] = 1;
        std::cout << seconds[i];

    }

    this->calculateTimeAndReport(seconds, sizeSeconds, greens);
}
```

В метод передается массив секунд и количество элементов массива. В seconds все хорошо, поступают все элементы. В greens только первых два, остальных нет. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В коде, который вы представили, ошибок не видно.

А что означает «остальных нет»? Что происходит в момент присвоения? Что видно в отладчике?

Comment: > а студия уже поддерживает расширения от gcc?

    int greens[sizeSeconds];

sizeSeconds - не константа ведь.

Comment: Не было тэга "С++".

Comment: Все там есть.

С другой стороны, раз уж пишите на плюсах, почему не использовать std::vector?

Да, ответ ниже абсолютно не в тему:)

Comment: Вообще сам пишу на Objective-C. Дали задачу, реализовать на плюсах. Плюсами занимался очень давно и то, не до конца.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо. `int *greens = new int[sizeSeconds];`

Comment: Не забудьте `delete`.

Comment: Кстати, да. Спасибо.